# Reading named colors from pods assets

Tags: swift, frameworks, uicolor

i have created my framework which include named colors that will be used in application but when i run the application it crashes with null error even color is included in assets file of pod.

example code?

```
   static var blue:UIColor = UIColor(named: "AppBlueColor")!
```

it crashed with null exception. please help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a resource bundle that contains your image files in your podspec like this:

```
s.resources = "Sources/Images.xcassets"
```

Also run `pod install` after the setup.